# how to convert 2d drawings to 3drawing using three.js/webgl

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

Hi i am trying to draw the 2d objects in the canvas using js.if click the button it will change to 3d object in another canvas which is in same page.
I tried using three.js.if i want draw 3d object,i am giving the points manually in the code.but i dont know how to convert into 3d coordinates. please suggest any ideas

this is my code for drawing geomentry plan

```
   function init() 
   {
 // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
// CAMERA
   var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT =  window.innerHeight;
   var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
  scene.add(camera);
  camera.position.set(0,150,400);
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);    
  // RENDERER
  if ( Detector.webgl )
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
   else
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
   container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
   container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
// EVENTS
   THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
   THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });
// CONTROLS
   controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
// STATS
   stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
   stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
   stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
   container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
   // LIGHT
   var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
   light.position.set(0,250,0);
   scene.add(light);
// FLOOR
   var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/checkerboard.jpg' );
   floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
  var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
  floor.position.y = -0.5;
  floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
  scene.add(floor);
  // SKYBOX/FOG
  var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
  var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9999ff,    side: THREE.BackSide } );
    var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
       scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x9999ff, 0.00025 );

  var starPoints = [];
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 (   10, 50 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 (  50, 100 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 (  100, 150 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 (  150, 200 ) );

 /*starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 (  30, -50 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 (   0, -20 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( -30, -50 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( -20, -10 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( -40,  10 ) );
  starPoints.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( -10,  10 ) );*/

   var starShape = new THREE.Shape( starPoints );

   var extrusionSettings = {
    size: 30, height: 4, curveSegments: 3,
    bevelThickness: 1, bevelSize: 2, bevelEnabled: false,
    material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1
    };

    var starGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( starShape,   extrusionSettings );

    var materialFront = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00   } );
    var materialSide = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff8800 } );
    var materialArray = [ materialFront, materialSide ];
    var starMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);

    var star = new THREE.Mesh( starGeometry, starMaterial );
    star.position.set(0,50,0);
    scene.add(star);

   // add a wireframe to model
    var wireframeTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, wireframe: true, transparent: true } ); 
   var star = new THREE.Mesh( starGeometry, wireframeTexture );
   star.position.set(0,50,0);
   scene.add(star);
   }

   function animate() 
   {
   requestAnimationFrame( animate );
   render();        
    update();
    }

  function update()
   {
   if ( keyboard.pressed("z") ) 
   { 
   // do something

    }
    controls.update();
    stats.update();
   }

   function render() 
   {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to help,

You can visit this :
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Extrusion.html

The method is:

```
var extrusionSettings = {
        size: 30, height: 4, curveSegments: 3,
        bevelThickness: 1, bevelSize: 2, bevelEnabled: false,
        material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1
    };

    var starGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( starShape, extrusionSettings );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I already saw this url..i dont  know how to change the 2d coordinates to 3d coordinates

Comment: I have used babylon.js.get into babylon.js...you will get some ideas

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean creating a 3d point from a constructor? 
If so, it is just one line in three.js.

```
 new THREE.Vector3( x, y, z );
```